# Will everyone skip a prime in this game?

Tags: prime-numbers

Suppose there are n people sitting at a round table. The game begins with the first person saying the number $1$. Then the game proceeds as follows:

Players take turns going round the table.
If the next number is composite, say that number and your turn ends.
If the number is prime, skip it and say the next composite number, then your turn ends.

Can you prove, that for all $n > 0$, every player will eventually skip a prime?

Example game for $n = 6$:

- Player 1: $1$
- **Player 2 (skips $2$ and $3$, as they are prime): $4$**
- **Player 3 (skips $5$): $6$**
- **Player 4 (skips $7$): $8$**
- Player 5: $9$
- Player 6: $10$
- **Player 1 (skips $11$): $12$**
- Player 2 (skips $13$): $14$
- Player 3: $15$
- Player 4: $16$
- **Player 5 (skips $17$): $18$**
- **Player 6 (skips $19$): $20$**

and at this point every player has skipped a prime at least once.

Update: a stronger verion of this problem (idenical to the one suggested in the comments) is posed as a conjecture on [OEIS A014689](https://oeis.org/A014689) by Zhi-Wei Sun

Comment: In other words, if $c_m$ denotes the $m$th composite number, we want to prove that no subsequence of the form $\{c_{qn+a+1}-c_{qn+a}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ (where $q$ and $a$ are fixed integers) is identically $1$.

Comment: A stronger version of the problem would be ask if every player will skip a prime even if the game begins from a any arbitrary integer $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The paper [Strings of congruent primes](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0024610799007863) by D.K.L. Shiu contains a useful result for this problem:

> **Theorem 1.** For each $q, a$ with $\gcd(q,a) = 1$ and large $x$, there exists a string of primes $$p_{n+1} \equiv p_{n+2} \equiv \dots \equiv p_{n+k} \equiv a \pmod q,$$ where $p_{n+k} < x$ and $$k \gg \left(\frac{\log\log x \log\log\log\log x}{(\log\log\log x)^2}\right)^{1/\phi(q)}.$$

(Here and in the rest of the answer, $p_n$ denotes the $n^{\text{th}}$ prime number.)

This is a generalization of Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions: it says that we can find arbitrarily long sequences of *consecutive* primes that are all contained in the progression $a,a+q,a+2q,a+3q,\dots$.

(For example, this theorem says that there are arbitrarily long sequences of consecutive primes that end in the digit $1$. A search in Mathematica says that the first time there are three consecutive primes like that is $p_{650}=4831$, $p_{651}=4861$, $p_{652}=4871$. The first time there are four consecutive primes like that is $p_{2516}=22501$, $p_{2517}=22511$, $p_{2518}=22531$, $p_{2519} = 22541$. And we can find $k$ consecutive primes like this for any $k$.)

In the prime-skipping game, let $q$ be the number of players; we will use the simpler statement that we can find $q$ consecutive primes $p_{n+1}, p_{n+2}, \dots, p_{n+q}$ that are all congruent to $1$ modulo $q$. Here is how we use this fact:

1. We wait for the game to get to prime $p_{n+1}$. Call the player who gets to that prime "Alice". Alice will skip $p_{n+1}$ and say $p_{n+1}+1$, which is congruent to $2$ modulo $q$. From then on, until the next prime is skipped, all players will be locked in a cycle modulo $q$. Alice will only say numbers that are $2$ modulo $q$, the player after Alice will only say numbers that are $3$ modulo $q$, the player before Alice will only say numbers that are $1$ modulo $q$, etc.
2. The next prime, $p_{n+2}$, is also $1$ modulo $q$. So the player before Alice will get to it - skipping it, and saying $p_{n+2}+1$ instead. This shifts the cycle: now the player before Alice says all the numbers that are $2$ modulo $q$, Alice says numbers that are $3$ modulo $q$, and so on; crucially, the player $2$ steps before Alice gets all the numbers $1$ modulo $q$.
3. The next prime, $p_{n+3}$, is *also* $1$ modulo $q$. So the player $2$ steps before Alice will skip it. The cycle shifts again...
4. ...and you see where this is going: the player who skips $p_{n+j}$ will be the player $j-1$ steps before Alice, for $j=1, \dots, q$. In particular, every player will get to skip one of the $q$ primes $p_{n+1}, \dots, p_{n+q}$.

Shiu's theorem also implies that there are infinitely many such strings of consecutive primes (because any particular string has a maximum length it works for, but there are arbitrarily long strings). It follows that the stronger conjecture about the prime-skipping game also holds: if we start at an arbitrary integer, eventually we will still get to a string of consecutive primes that are $1$ modulo $q$ - and that string will cause all $q$ players to skip a prime.

---

Note that for the primes in the string that helped us solve the prime-skipping game, the set $$\{p_{n+1} - (n+1), p_{n+2} - (n+2), \dots, p_{n+q} - (n+q)\}$$ intersects every residue class modulo $q$. Since there are infinitely many such strings, it follows that the sequence $p_n - n$ visits each residue class modulo $q$ infinitely many times. This proves the conjecture in a comment from  Zhi-Wei Sun on OEIS sequence [A014689](https://oeis.org/A014689).